# Is it possible to have an image as legend of a fieldset?

Tags: html

I have page like this

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Username</legend>
  <p>Information about the user</p>
</fieldset>
```

But I'd much rather have the user's avatar in the legend (and if so is it supported by the major browsers). Is this possible or do I have to go down the div route?

Comment: Div route I'm guessing, fieldset only displays text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this and it does seem you are able to use images within the legend. See a working example here
http://jsfiddle.net/qyWjM/

Here is the code

```
<fieldset>
  <legend><img src="http://cdn.orkin.com/images/rodents/deer-mouse-illustration_360x244.jpg" height=50 width=50></legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd also fiddled it and seen some promising results. As the commentor above said though all the docs I've seen say it doesn't. Hence the question.

Comment: Yeah I have tested Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox all seem to be working. JSfiddle doesn't even work for me on IE8 so enough said about that one.

Comment: Great, undocumented feature!

Comment: I've been doing a project lately using fieldset and legend quite a lot (excess of 50), never thought to check if images could be used. Now that I know they can, my mind is beginning to attack me, really hope it doesn't win.

Answer (score 1):

The content model of `legend` is “inline” (in [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-LEGEND)) or “phrase level” (in [HTML5 CR](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-legend-element)), and this allows text and text-level markup, including `img` elements. So there is no reason why an `img` inside `legend` would not work. Although the rendering of `fieldset` and `legend` has some specialties, they do not affect the way images are rendered.

As usual with images, there is the issue that the image might not always be rendered, but this can be handled the usual way. If you wish to present an image *instead of* a user name, you would naturally make the user name the `alt` text:

```
<legend><img src=yucca.png alt=Yucca></legend>
```

And if you use it *in addition to* a user name, the `alt` text should be empty:

```
<legend><img src=yucca.png alt=""> Yucca</legend>
```

On the other hand, using a user name or an avatar image is perhaps not such a great idea. The `legend` is supposed to be sort-of caption or heading for the data in the `fieldset`, and normally the user name and the avatar are *data* (possibly to be prompted for), rather than caption for data. So a more normal `legend` would be “User name” (literally), and the actual user name would then appear under it.